# some functionalities not working in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on bootstrap dateRange picker. Please find my working demo  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FD56Xd?p=preview)

Below are the issues i'm facing:

- The dates are not highlighting when user is selecting the range.
- There are some options like Today,Yesterday,Last 7 Days..Custom in
  the datepicker which are not working When we click on the datepicker
  field.
- The calendar displayed is showing some old dates(November 2014 and December
  2014).

Any suggestions to resolve this errors would be helpful. Are there any dateRange pickers available in angularjs and bootstrap which makes work easier.

PS: I want to look my dateRange picker as shown in the [link](http://demo.improvely.com/reports/webshop/ads?imt=1&utm_campaign=Date%20Range%20Picker&utm_source=Site%20Ads&utm_medium=Banner&utm_content=Blog%20Demo%20Image.)

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var cb = function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    console.log("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ", label = " + label + "]");
  }

  var optionSet1 = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    minDate: '08/01/2014',
    maxDate: '12/31/2014',
    dateLimit: {
      days: 60
    },
    showDropdowns: true,
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 1,
    timePicker12Hour: true,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: 'left',
    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
    applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'btn-small',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    locale: {
      applyLabel: 'Submit',
      cancelLabel: 'Clear',
      fromLabel: 'From',
      toLabel: 'To',
      customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
      daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      firstDay: 1
    }
  };

  $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);

  $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("show event fired");
  });
  $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("hide event fired");
  });
  $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  });
  $('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("cancel event fired");
  });
});
```

--EDITED--

I have following imports in my application.

```
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <script src="moment.js"></script>
```

I see no error in my console, but functionality is not working, the text field is blank and onclick of it, its not showing the calendar.

Please advice.[image]

Comment: _The calendar displayed is showing some old dates(November 2014 and December 2014)_ -- why are these options being set, when all other options work off current day? --> `minDate: '08/01/2014', maxDate: '12/31/2014'` -- try removing...

Comment: @WhiteHat - I have the min and the latest date coming from backend application which i need to set in the js code.Please find my current working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/FD56Xd?p=preview . I need to set those minDate and maxDate so that dates are enabled between that range and user can select date range between them.

Comment: You can't simultaneously say "the maximum selectable date is December 2014" (maxDate) and "the current selected date is yesterday" (startDate/endDate). They are in conflict. Your option values need to be consistent with each other.

Answer (score 1):

> The dates are not highlighting when user is selecting the range.

You have failed to load the daterangepicker.css stylesheet on your site. You linked some "daterangepicker-bs3.css" file which doesn't exist so that's just a 404 error.

> There are some options like Today,Yesterday,Last 7 Days..Custom in the datepicker which are not working When we click on the datepicker field.

You have set a `minDate` and `maxDate` dates of August to December 2014.

That means no date before August 2014 should be valid, and no date after December 2014 should be valid.

Today, yesterday, last week, etc are in 2017 not 2014, so they are not valid selections.

> The calendar displayed is showing some old dates(November 2014 and December 2014).

Again, because of your `minDate` and `maxDate` settings say that only dates in August to December 2014 are valid.

These conflicting settings are the cause of your troubles. Either your `minDate`/`maxDate` are wrong, or your `startDate`/`endDate`/`ranges` are wrong.

Comment: Please see my edited section in my question. I have imports required for the application, facing error $(..) daterangepicker is not a function. Do i need to have any other imports?Thanks. @Dan Grossman

Comment: i'm not seeing any errors in my applciation console but the functionality is not working.The text field  is blank and onclick its not showing any calendar.

Comment: Nobody has access to the page that isn't working but you. Your "working demo" doesn't have that problem, the code you shared doesn't have that problem, so nobody other than you has visibility into what you've done wrong.

Comment: Agree. Please find the demo in http://plnkr.co/edit/mnMeJw0a0UDZfC38rQ5G?p=preview . I want to replicate my local workspace issue here in plunker, however i can see few js exceptions on the console,In order to avoid them i have downloaded daterangepicker-bs3.css,daterangepicker.js and kept locally but still of no use.Thanks.